# Strictly convex iff concave upward?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, convex-analysis

I need to prove the following theorem:

Let $f$ be a function that is twice differentiable on $(a,b)$, then $f$ is strictly convex if and only if $f$ is concave upward.

I have no idea how to start. I know that I need to prove the statement in both directions, that is:

1. $f$ is strictly convex $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is concave upward.
2. $f$ is concave upward $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is strictly convex.

Can anybody help me, or give some suggestions on how to prove this?

Comment: [Concave upward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) is just a synonym for *convex* (unless you have a different definition).

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis is correct, and thus the assertion is not true, because strictly convex is a stricter condition than convex, so the implication only works in one direction.